# unable to install mysqlclient to connect django to mysql db on my mac

Tags: mysql, django

I'm new to mac, python and django. This will be my second project.

I use to have a django environment working on my old windows pc but, that also came with many weeks of struggle to get it working.

Now I've been struggling through article after article on the web but, with absolutely no progress for 2 weeks.

I just keep getting this issue.....

```
(klsapp) normancollett@Normans-MacBook-Air klsapp % pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-658q_j90
       cwd: /private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/include/mysql -I/Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-record-tb3ltsu9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient
         cwd: /private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/include/mysql -I/Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-install-nkn6549a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gy/lrnz57_x27z52f77rgshj80w0000gn/T/pip-record-tb3ltsu9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/normancollett/Documents/GitHub/klsapp/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
(klsapp) normancollett@Normans-MacBook-Air klsapp %
```

Comment: I think you should tag this question primarily with "python", "macos", and "pip". You should also add information which pip and which python you are using. On the Mac you usually have the system tools in /usr/bin and then a parallel toolchain from homebrow or macports. can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by reinstalling python3 via Homebrew.

Uninstall python following this link https://macflypro.com/uninstall-guides/remove-python.html

Then reinstalled by going to terminal using this command:

```
brew install python3
```

Then from my venv environment I managed to successfully run:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do not have an installation of SSL library detected.

First thing you can try is to update your compile toolchain with `xcode-select --install`.

If this doesn't work, try installing the openssl library:

```sh
brew install openssl
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

Finally, you can try to install your dependencies using the "Conda" package manager; this is the bulkiest but easy method since it will handle all the OpenSSL dependencies and version for you.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I have tried your first two suggestions but, they don't seem to solve the problem. However, I have not yet tried the "Conda" package manager option. Do you perhaps have some guidance on how I go about using "Conda"?

Comment: You can follow Miniconda's official installation instructions to get Conda. After installation, you can run `conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient` to install the client.

Answer (score 0):

May be your python and PIP are incompatible. Please uninstall Python and PIP and try installing freshly.

1) [Download and install python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (Make sure you install 64-bit version)

2) Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

3) python3 get-pip.py

4) pip3 install mysqlclient

Comment: He is on Mac OS!

Comment: Changed step 2.